# What the correct syntax for StringWithData?

Tags: string, swift, nsdata

Objective-C:

```
- (NSString *)stringWithData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return result;
}
```

Swift Pattern:

```
convenience init(bytes bytes: UnsafePointer<Void>, length length: Int, encoding encoding: UInt)
```

My interpretation:

```
func stringWithData(data:NSData) -> String {
        let result = NSString.(data:data, length:data.length, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
```

I'm getting a compiler error: "Expectant member name followed by '.'"

What am I missing (I'm suspecting it has to do with the 1st parameter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Playground:

```
let data = "test".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)! as NSData
// NSConcreteMutableData
let result = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) // "test"
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.` after `NSString` in your `let result = ...` line.

Comment: The compiler didn't like the 'length' parameter. So 
a)remove the '.' per your suggestion AND 
b)remove the length parameter; as indicated by Mundi's feedback from his playground, below.